# Javascript Eval error with numbers having leading zeroes

Tags: javascript, math, eval, padding, zero

I was trying to do maths based on variables and use the outcome. The input sometimes has padding with leading zeroes at the start of it. Today while debugging my code I have found out the following;
`eval("1*010 + -9")` evaluates to -1 while `eval("1*10 + -9")` evaluates to 1

I do not have any idea how this could be possible since these following evaluations work as intended

`eval("1*009 + -9")` evaluates to 0

`eval("1*011 + -9")` evaluates to 2

Any explanation would be helpful, thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: `010 === 8` (octal). Don't use leading zeros, call `Number` directly on the text, eg `Number('010')` ( `=== 10`)

Comment: Yeah I have just realised aswell, well it is odd that the javascript treats such numbers as octal for no reason. Thanks for the quick reply